# How to stub computed properties during unit testing?

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon, chai

say we have an object

```
var myObject = Ember.Object.create({
  enable: function(){
    //a method which has a lot of calculations and returns a boolean
  }.property("someDependency"),
  disable: Ember.computed.not("enable")
})
```

I test the property `enable` separately, now I want to test the property `disable` separately & I just want to stub `enable` so that my test cases be simple.

I tried

```
myObject.set("enable", true)
```

but this is not right as we need to define a setter(which is not the case for all the computed properties)

```
sinon.stub(myObject, "enable")
```

also fails because `Ember.computed` returns an `object` but sinon needs a method as second argument

So, the question is what's the correct way to `stub` computed properties in ember 0.9.8 ?

Comment: I think that you receive an error when using `var myObject = Ember.Object.create(...` isn't possible to create an object with computed properties.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior No we don't get an error, which version of ember do you use ? right now I use 0.9.8 though

Comment: The lastest 1.2.0, I tested with 1.0.pre and no error is throwed, so forget my last comment :)

Answer (score 4):

I figured out one way to do this(not exactly stubbing though), just want to know what everyone thinks about this

```
beforeEach(function(){
  object.reopen({enable: true});
})

it('should be false when enable is true', function(){
  expect(object.get("disable")).to.be.false;
})
```

Comment: Did you mean `object.reopen({ enabled: true });`? I don't know if `object.reopen("enable", true);` works ...